# Why is Azure Media Services putting a metadata.xml file in my thumbnails asset?

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm basically using the standard contoso project to play around with azure media services.

When I upload my video and encode (I'm using the clip, thumbnail, and video pipeline steps) my thumbnails do not work when I go to the video list on the web client.

I've found out that the reason for this is that Media Services is adding a metadata xml file to the asset containing my thumbnails so when I process the output urls to my cms it is listing the xml file as one of the thumbnails.  Keep in mind that this is the exact same metadata file that is generated and stored in the clip asset.

Is this file supposed to be included in the asset generated with my thumbnail picture(s)?  I don't think so because the code processing the outputs in my thumbnail pipeline step gets all the files in that particular asset and creates the urls for each file.  The Web Client then seems to grab the first one in the list and use it as a source for the thumbnail viewed on the page, and of course its not an image file so it doesn't show anything.

I'm pretty sure I can fix the problem by checking to see if each file in that asset is an image first before adding it to my cms as a thumbnail image but I want to know if it supposed to be there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - during any encode Task sent to Azure Media Encoder, we generate a metadata XML that describes the input Asset, and write that XML to the output.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783120.aspx for more details. This feature shipped in August 2014 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj884319.aspx)